# Printer dialog won't popup

Tags: vb.net

I have to print **string** to POS printer with option to show PrintDialog or without it.
With showed code printing without dialog (pDialog = FALSE) goes OK but with dialog don't want.

```
    Imports System.Drawing
    Imports System.Drawing.Printing
    Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

    ...
    If pDialog Then
        Dim pd As New PrintDialog()
        pd.PrinterSettings = New PrinterSettings()
        If (pd.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
            cls_RAW_print.PrintRaw(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, pStr)
        End If
    Else
        ''Print without dialog
        cls_RAW_print.PrintRaw(winprintername, pStr)
    End If
```

If pDialog is TRUE error is not generated and dialog is not showed and string is not printed.
Program simply step over pd.ShowDialog silently.

Is here any obvious reason why PrinterDialog don't popup and how to get it?
Can here be a problem that this code is in module?

Comment: Have you tried passing the calling form as the owner?

Comment: Do you think call dialog as pd.ShowDialog(Me)? I do try that with same result, don't work for some reason.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code?  Do you know if it's even hitting pd.ShowDialog?

Comment: I do. Program passes through ShowDialog without error. I try same code with empty project and there work as expected. Real mistery!

Comment: Try changing it to Dim pd As New System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog

Otherwise, I might want to know more about what's happening BEFORE you get here...

Comment: That will be hard since I work on HUGE project. But now I try to move this function closer to beginning of a program and even on the mymainForm_Load. And code don't work nowhere. I have referenced system.drawing and system.drawing.printing and interopservices for whole project from project properties/references. That all seem that some reference for printing may be missing or some is too much?

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party components?  How about checking the .NET level?  What about the platform?  Are all of your binaries being built when they're supposed to be built?  Check the application manifest for errors?  If it's not running on form load then it's an issue with the project, more than likely, and not with any code.

As a last resort you could create a brand-new project, and copy everything over.

Comment: Yes, I should check all of that as much I can/know. Project have many files and it would be hard to recompose it from beginning. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @Nathan, Finally find a cause of problem and solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902098/why-is-the-printdialog-not-displaying-in-64-bit

Comment: Aha!  I knew it had to be something having to do with the platform.